# How to show html template in ckeditor using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using window popup and selecting template from that window. Now I want to show selected html template in ckeditor in another window.

I tried following code but is showing me html content in ckeditor instead of html template.

```
function sendValue(selvalue){
$.getJSON("A2B_entity_mailtemplate.php", { id: ""+ selvalue, action: "load" },
function(data){
    window.opener.CKEDITOR.instances.msg_mail.setData(unescape(data.messagetext));
    window.opener.document.getElementById('from').value = data.fromemail;
    window.opener.document.getElementById('fromname').value = data.fromname;
    window.opener.document.getElementById('subject').value = data.subject;
    window.close();
});
```

}

I have also tried following but it is also not working for me.

```
if (window.opener.CKEDITOR.instances.msg_mail.mode == 'wysiwyg') {
    window.opener.CKEDITOR.instances.msg_mail.insertHtml(unescape(data.messagetext));
} else {
        window.opener.CKEDITOR.instances.msg_mail.setMode('wysiwyg', function() {
       window.opener.CKEDITOR.instances.msg_mail.insertHtml(unescape(data.messagetext));
        window.opener.CKEDITOR.instances.msg_mail.setMode('source');
    });
}
```

So how can I get html template instead of html content in ckeditor?
Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Really not clear what you are wanting or trying to do